# Contour integration with delta functions

Tags: contour-integration, residue-calculus, dirac-delta

One wants to calculate the time dependent voltage, $V(t)$, of an electric circuit with impedance $$Z(\omega) = \frac{R + i \omega L}{(1 - \omega^2 CL) + i \omega CR}$$
and a current $$I(t) = I_0 \cos(\Omega t)$$
My initial approach was by calculating the voltage in frequency space, $V(\omega) = I(\omega)Z(\omega)$, and then carry out an inverse Fourier transform on $V(\omega)$ to get $V(t)$.

With $I(\omega) = I_0\pi\biggl(\delta(\omega - \Omega) + \delta(\omega + \Omega)\biggl)$, it gives $$V(t) = \frac{I_0}{2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \biggl(\delta(\omega - \Omega) + \delta(\omega + \Omega)\biggl) \frac{(R + i \omega L)e^{i\omega t}}{(1 - \omega^2 CL) + i \omega CR} d\omega$$
There are 2 poles in the integrand, namely $$\omega_\pm = i\biggl(\frac{R}{2L} \pm \sqrt{\biggl(\frac{R}{2L}\biggl)^2 - \frac{1}{LC}}\biggl)$$
and therefore one can rewrite the inverse transform as $$V(t) = \frac{I_0}{2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \biggl(\delta(\omega - \Omega) + \delta(\omega + \Omega)\biggl) \frac{(R + i \omega L)e^{i\omega t}}{(-LC)(\omega - \omega _+)(\omega - \omega _-)} d\omega$$
I would usually then solve the integral by contour integration, with a semi-circular contour closing in the positive half, where both poles will be enclosed. One can then get the answer by residue theorem.

However, what I am unsure of is how to do the contour integration when there are also delta functions involved? Since if I just solve it using the normal behaviour of delta functions, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(x-x_0)f(x) dx = f(x_0)$, it doesn't give the correct answer.

NB. I am able to get the correct answer by calculating $Z(t)$ and then get $V(t)$ by convolution theorem, but I want to be able to do it by the above method as well.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you do not get the correct result by simply using the sifting property of the delta functions?

Comment: @ Ron Gordon This was actually a question from my University work and the answer obtained from just using the shifting property of delta functions does not agree with the official answer given for the problem.

Comment: "That's a boy's answer. A boy who goes chasing [inverse transforms] on the word of a man who wouldn't even tell you where to start. [...] That's what a fool does. You don't strike me as a fool, [Student 1]. So, I'll ask you again, there must be a reason." - Alberforth Dumbledore.  (Translation: do you even believe the "official answer"?)

Comment: @Ron Gordon When one calculates $V(t)$ by using the convolution theorem (i.e. the method I described at the end in "NB..."), there are several differences between this and the answer one gets from simply following the shifting property of delta functions. More specifically, the most striking difference is that there is a factor of $e^{\frac{-Rt}{2L}}$ from using the convolution method, which can't be obtained from what you proposed.